# Найти элемент в массиве

Tags: javascript

Функция проверяет массив на элемент.

Если есть возвращает строчку, если нет `null` .

Как в строчке *(9) возвратить это значение?

```js
arr = [56, NaN, 'Yes', 'Arrrgh'];
arr2 = [];

function checkArr(arr, str) {
  for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    if (str === arr[i]) {
      arr2.push(str)
    }
    /*  arr2.push('null') return; 
Если удалить эту строчку,то возвращаться будут все строчки которые были найдены. 
Если первое условие If не нашло схожих элементов,значит условие переходит сюда и тут условие должно
вставить в конец массива строчку 'null' . Вот вывод без этой строчки ( 56,Yes,Arrrgh) второй параметр не был найден checkArr(arr, undefined) должен* возвращать null поэтому он должен вернуть (56,null,Yes,Arrrgh) */
  }
}

//комментарии в конце функции забыл убрать
checkArr(arr, 56); // 0
checkArr(arr, undefined); // 1
checkArr(arr, 'Yes'); // 2
checkArr(arr, 'Arrrgh'); // -1
alert(arr2)
```

Comment: Вы разбаловались после Вашего первого вопроса. Тогда я смог догадаться, что Вам было нужно, но теперь *даже мне* сделать это не представляется возможным. И пишите текст вопроса в теле вопроса, а не в заголовке.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
arr = [56, NaN, 'Yes', 'Arrrgh'];
arr2 = [];

function checkArr(src, dst, item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < src.length; i++) {
    if (item === src[i]) {
      dst.push(item);
      return;
    }
  }
  dst.push(null);
}


checkArr(arr, arr2, 56); // 0
checkArr(arr, arr2, undefined); // 1
checkArr(arr, arr2, 'Yes'); // 2
checkArr(arr, arr2, 'Arrrgh'); // -1
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr2));
console.log(arr2);
```

Comment: С Json пока не работал.Не совсем понимаю,что здесь происходит.мне хотелось бы узнать как вернуть эту не найденную переменную в массив теми наборами команд,которыми я овладел на начальном уровне.Спасибо за решение

Comment: @ДинисХасанов `JSON.stringify` - это всего лишь форматирование массива в одну строку. Этот вызов можно убрать.